# add class with JQuery traversing

Tags: jquery, html

How would you go about adding column specific classes to the table below with JQuery traversing? ( last column in my case )

i started to dab around quite hoplessly with something along the line of

> $('#myID
>   tr').children("td:not(:first)").addClass("me");

like I said, hopelessly. Please pass me some help.

```
<table id="myID" class="myClass">
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
        <th>three</th>
        <th>four</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <th>c</th>
        <th>d</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**SOLUTION:**

> $('#myID tr').children("td:nth-last-of-type(1)").addClass("me");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) instead

```
$('#myID tr').children("td:not(:first-of-type)").addClass("me");
```

Or [`first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
$('#myID tr').children("td:not(:first-child)").addClass("me");
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dBR3b/)

Comment: @mornenel You forgot to include jQuery library see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eGHSE/1/)!